# How to scanning path in docker image from BlackDuck scanning

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, containers, blackduck, synopsis-detect

I'm using BlackDuck scanning use script detect.sh from Synopsys to scan docker image but I don't know how to scan path in docker image. My setting below:

```
./detect.sh \
--blackduck.url=https://blackduck.blackducksoftware.com \
--blackduck.always.trust.cert=true \
--blackduck.trust.cert=true \
--blackduck.api.token=\"%env.BD_HUB_TOKEN%\" \
--detect.project.name=\"%black_duck_parent_project%\" \
--detect.project.version.name="Docker-Image" \
--detect.code.location.name="Docker-Image-Scan" \
--detect.tools.excluded=DETECTOR \
--logging.level.com.synopsys.integration=DEBUG \
--detect.detector.search.depth=10000 \
--detect.docker.image=myapp:latest \
--detect.project.codelocation.unmap=true \
--detect.output.path=.\blackduck \
--detect.detector.search.exclusion.defaults=true \
--detect.policy.check.fail.on.severities=BLOCKER,CRITICAL \
--logging.level.com.synopsys=DEBUG \
--detect.report.timeout=1200 \
--blackduck.timeout=240
```

I want to scan directory /opt/scanning, /opt/checking in my docker image.
How to scan that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Advanced BackDuck Docker Inspector documentation](https://blackducksoftware.github.io/blackduck-docker-inspector/latest/advanced/#running-the-signature-scanner-on-a-specific-directory-within-a-docker-image):

> Running Synopsys Detect on a project directory that exists within a
> Docker image
>
> When you want to run Synopsys Detect on a directory that
> exists within a Docker image, you can use the following approach: 1.
> Run Synopsys Detect on the image to generate the container filesystem
> for the image. 2. Run Synopsys Detect on a directory within that
> container filesystem.
>
> Synopsys Detect performs these actions without running the
> image/container.
>
> To see a simple example that illustrates this approach, use the following commands to download these sample files:

`curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blackducksoftware/blackduck-docker-inspector/master/deployment/docker/runDetectInImageDir/runDetectInImageDir.sh`
`curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blackducksoftware/blackduck-docker-inspector/master/deployment/docker/runDetectInImageDir/Dockerfile`

> Review the script before running it to make sure the side effects
> (files and directories that it creates) are acceptable. You must make
> the script executable before you run it.

`runDetectInImageDir.sh` contains the following script, which "provides a simple illustration of how you might run detect on a specific
directory (say, a maven project) within an image, without running that image as a container":

```
curl -O https://detect.synopsys.com/detect.sh
chmod +x detect.sh

./detect.sh
  --blackduck.offline.mode=true
  --detect.docker.image=mavenproject:1
  --detect.docker.passthrough.output.path=/tmp/output
  --detect.tools.excluded=SIGNATURE_SCAN,POLARIS

rm -rf containerfilesystem
mkdir -p containerfilesystem
cd containerfilesystem
tar xvf /tmp/output/mavenproject_1_containerfilesystem.tar.gz

cd image_mavenproject_v_1/home/my-app
../../../../detect.sh
  --blackduck.offline.mode=true
  --detect.tools.excluded=SIGNATURE_SCAN,POLARIS
```

Make sure you read the instructions in the sample files! Of course, amongst others, you have to replace `image_mavenproject_v_1/home/my-app` by your path.